# Dynamic header using state NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create dynamic headers using state in NextJs, my values however are blank when I view the page source. I suspect my state is not being resolved before the render method fires. Why would the rest of my content load in the render method but not the head ? Example code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

myContent() {
    const {name} = this.state
    return (
        <h1>{name}</h1>
    )
}

render() {
    const {myDescription} = this.state
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta name='description' content={myDescription} /> 
            </Head>
            {this.myContent()}
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const fetchMyData = await fetch('https://myapi.com')
    const fetchedMyData = await fetchMyData.json()   

    return {
        props: {
            data: fetchedMyData.entries,           
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried moving the head into the `myContent()` method. Same issue.

Comment: You're missing the class definition

Comment: Was just a sample to hone into my issue, hence the reduced code. Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: can you readd the class definition (something like `export default MyComponent {` at the start after the imports, then `}` before the `getServerSideProps` definition line)

Comment: I excluded the class definition, constructor etc to avoid the clutter.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72873497/edit) the question to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (the minimal amount of code that itself is runnable but still shows the issue)

Comment: Please show us the full code for that page component. The most likely scenario is that you're only setting the description value on the client-side, hence why it doesn't appear on the page source.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was attempting to pass client side data to the server. I needed to utilise the [context](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) param then retrieve from props.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { params } = context
    const fetchMyData = await fetch('https://myapi.com')
    const fetchedMyData = await fetchMyData.json()   

    return {
        props: {
            data: fetchedMyData.entries,  
            params,         
        }
    }
}
```